# Is there a equivalent of libxml2.HTMLparser.htmlSAXParseDoc in Java?

Tags: java, objective-c, c, libxml2

I would like to get (almost) exactly the same result of htmlSAXParseDoc in Java, for an Android mail parsing module.

Specifically, since [mailcore 2](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/bf9061a79c7f0ee52cc781ca356a4e273a641270/src/core/basetypes/MCString.cpp) uses htmlSAXParseDoc to "flatten" html (in method "flattenHTMLAndShowBlockquoteAndLink"), with certain state passed in as parameter. I wonder if there are similar method in Java libraries, such as in Jsoup?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it looks like Android does have libxml2 included in its core package. Will go from there first.